# YouTube Data API: Choosing the destination YT channel when uploading my video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I've followed the steps explained here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video in order to use their script to upload a video on my channel.

The problem is that my GMail account is associated to two YouTube channels: my personal one which is its default YT channel, and a new one that I've created this morning. The latter is the good destination channel for my videos.

How can I tell the YouTube Data API to upload the video to this channel and not the default one? I didn't see anything useful in the Console API "YouTube Data API", nore in the technical documentation of the upload script (given above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow, you will be presented, within the browser, with the option of selecting to which account your app is to be given access rights.

You may well exercise this behavior, prior to making use of your script, with the help of [Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Upon a successful OAuth flow, you may verify (and also revoke) the permissions granted by your account on the [account's permissions page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).